# Is there a way to load a leaflet map instance without providing the map div container id?

Tags: leaflet

From what I was able to find so far, it seems that the parent map div container must be available before I can instantiate a leafletjs map instance.

Is there a way to get the map instance content without providing the map container id?
My goal is to have something like this, so that I won't have to rely on an onload event to load the map in the page:

```
function getView() {
    return `<div id="testLocations">
            <div id="map">
                ${loadMap()}
            </div>
    </div>`;
}

function loadMap() {
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);
    
    var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.").openPopup();

    return <map html content here>;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, it's impossible to initiate the map object before the map container initialized in the DOM.

If you add the map div element before creating the map object it will be ok.